# PHP date function for week error

Tags: php, date

I am trying to create a function which will take a sent date and then get all dates till a week ago. I have had a look at the follow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336919/return-dates-of-current-calendar-week-as-array-in-php5) and it does something similar to what I am trying to do. So using the code in the question here is what I have:

```
$currentDay = "2014-02-25";
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 7 ; $i++) {
    echo date('Y-m-d', $currentDay) . '<br />';
    $currentDay -= 24 * 3600;
}
```

When running this I get the following output:

```
1970-01-01
1969-12-31
1969-12-30
1969-12-29
1969-12-28
1969-12-27
1969-12-26
```

How can I make it that I get this instead:

```
2014-02-25
2014-02-24
2014-02-23
2014-02-22
2014-02-21
2014-02-20
2014-02-19
2014-02-18
```

Is there a problem with the way the date function has been used?

Comment: Yes, use $currentDay = strtotime('2014-02-25');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your date variable in [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime), the second argument for the `date()` function accepts a Unix timestamp which is why you're getting 1969/1970 etc - when incorrect formats are passed into `date()`, it defaults to [the Unix epoch which is Jan 1 1970](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

```
$currentDay = strtotime("2014-02-25");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple example:

```php
$day = new DateTime("2014-02-25");
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= 7 ; $i++) {
    echo $day->format('Y-m-d'), '<br />';
    $day->modify('-1 day');
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/105615)</kbd>